# Recursion troubles with "return undefined" (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I'm stuck with recursion.  I've read a few similar questions, but it brought me no relief.
My function works well inside, but it returns "undefined" at the end.

I have a binary tree. Now I'm trying to make a function, which can get me an answer: if any nodes on this level have children.

```
class tree_node {
    constructor(n_array, parent) {
        this.n_array = n_array;
        this.has_children = false;
        this.children = [];
        if (parent != null) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.level = this.parent.level + 1;
        }
        else {
            this.level = 0;
        }
        // run the tree
        this.child();
    }
    child() {
        if (this.n_array.length != 1) {
            this.has_children = true;
            let m = Math.floor(this.n_array.length / 2);
            let l = this.n_array.slice(0, m);
            let r = this.n_array.slice(m);
            const left = new tree_node(l, this);
            const right = new tree_node(r, this);
            this.children.push(left, right);
        }
        else return 0
    }

    get_if_node_has_children(node, level) {
        console.log(node.level, node.has_children)
        if (node.has_children && node.level < level) {
            console.log("in loop")
            node.children.forEach(element => {
                return element.get_if_node_has_children(element, level);
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log("first else")
            if (node.level == level && node.has_children) {
                console.log("node.level == level && node.has_children " + node.n_array)
                return true;
            }
            else {
                console.log("return false")
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    show() {
        console.log(this.n_array + " | Level: " + this.level + ". " + this.branch + " Has children = " + this.has_children);
        if (this.has_children) {
            this.children.forEach(element => {
                return element.show();
            });
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }    
}
```

`get_if_node_has_children(node, level)` work inside, so to speak. I've expected the exact behaviour and log. Except on thing: function returns "undefined". But I have no idea where I missed the point.

```js
let root = [];

class tree_node {
  constructor(n_array, parent) {
    this.n_array = n_array;
    this.has_children = false;
    this.children = [];
    // при создании экземпляра класса то parent == null
    if (parent != null) {
      this.parent = parent;
      this.level = this.parent.level + 1;
    } else {
      this.level = 0;
    }
    // run the tree
    this.child();
  }
  child() {
    if (this.n_array.length != 1) {
      this.has_children = true;
      let m = Math.floor(this.n_array.length / 2);
      let l = this.n_array.slice(0, m);
      let r = this.n_array.slice(m);
      const left = new tree_node(l, this);
      const right = new tree_node(r, this);
      this.children.push(left, right);
    } else return 0
  }

  get_if_node_has_children(node, level) {
    console.log(node.level, node.has_children)

    if (node.has_children && node.level < level) {
      console.log("in loop")
      node.children.forEach(element => {
        return element.get_if_node_has_children(element, level);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("first else")
      if (node.level == level && node.has_children) {
        console.log("node.level == level && node.has_children " + node.n_array)
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log("return false")
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  show() {
    console.log(this.n_array + " | Level: " + this.level + ". " + "Has children = " + this.has_children);
    if (this.has_children) {
      this.children.forEach(element => {
        return element.show();
      });
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  // CLASS END ===========================
}

root = new tree_node([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ])
console.log("=== root.show() ===")
root.show();
console.log("=== let a = root.get_if_node_has_children(root, 2) ===")
let a = root.get_if_node_has_children(root, 2)
console.log(" a is " + a)
```

Comment: `return` inside a `forEach` callback just returns from the callback, not the function the `forEach` is in. If you want to use `return` to exit the function, use `for-of` instead of `forEach` (it's less clunky anyway).

Comment: I've tried it before creating this question. 
It doesn't work either. With `for-of` the function stops after the first iteration.

Comment: That means you're returning unconditionally, without checking first if the value is waht you want. What is `get_nodes_with_children` supposed to do? It seems to return `true` or `false`, but the name suggests it should return a list or array of some kind.

Comment: Sorry, it was an old name from another attempt. Let  say its name is `get_if_node_has_children`
I can't see where I'm wrong in my logic... First I check - if the node has children and the level is higher. If so - I go into recursion. If the level is the one I want to check - then if it has children - I return true, otherwise - false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. `return` inside a callback (for instance, your `forEach` callback) just returns from the callback, not the function that called `forEach`. In general, in modern code, use `for-of` unless you need the index of the element.
2. You're not checking the result of the recursive call before returning it. But if the first child node you call it on returns `false`, you want to keep looking, rather than immediately returning `false`.

Fixing both:

```
get_if_node_has_children(node, level) {
    console.log(node.level, node.has_children)
    if (node.has_children && node.level < level) {
        console.log("in loop")
        for (const element of node.children) { // *** #1, using `for-of` instead of `forEach` so we can return below
            const hasChild = element.get_if_node_has_children(element, level);
            if (hasChild) {     // *** #2, only return here if you got `true`
                return true;    // *** 
            }                   // *** 
        }
        return false; // *** #2 part 2 -- didn't find it anywhere, return `false`
    } else {
        console.log("first else")
        if (node.level == level && node.has_children) {
            console.log("node.level == level && node.has_children " + node.n_array)
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("return false")
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd reorganize that slightly though, which is easier if I remove some no-longer-needed logging:

```
get_if_node_has_children(node, level) {
    console.log(node.level, node.has_children)
    if (node.has_children) {
        if (node.level === level) {
            return true;
        }
        if (node.level < level) {
            for (const element of node.children) {
                if (element.get_if_node_has_children(element, level)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll think about it deeper, I still can't get this recursion topic completely.
But few questions.

First - why `const` but not `let`. Second - is there any profit using `const hasChild = element.get_if_node_has_children(element, level);` but not strite away  `if (element.get_if_node_has_children(element, level))`

Comment: @DonBobskiy - Why not `const`? We never change the value of  `element`. I habitually use `const` for any binding (loosely, "variable") that I don't intend to change the value of. But `let` is fine too. Re the second: Thanks for pointing that out, that was a holdover from an earlier version and I should have consolidated those. :-) I've fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, now all sounds more clear. I understand now (and you've said it but I didn't get it first:) that my mistake was not checking `node.has_children` before using return...